# Seeking advice for adding GPU to mini PC

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, thin-mini-itx

I have purchased a ASUS K20CE style pc for my son, which has turned out not to have enough "omph" for playing even modest modern 3D games.

I went out and got a GeForce GT710 card for the PC (which matched one of the options that I could have ordered the PC with to begin with) but was faced with the problem, that the card did not fit the cabinet (times have changed much since I built my last PC it turns out!)

I guess the motherboard is a mini ITX one. It has a single PCI Express slot, and the cabinet is slim. I have my eyes on some alternative GPUs, that may fit the machine, but I hesitate to order as I realise the system has an external power adapter of at most 90W. Most GPU cards advertise 300-400W power requirements, so I am starting to wonder if it will work at all.

Does anybody have experience with such an upgrade or advice? The goal is not to make a monster gaming PC, but just a modest budget one.

Comment: You're not going to be able to play much with that processor. What games is he playing? If you are really set on using that motherboard you would have to have an external GPU (using something like a pcie extender) and an external powersupply. Also a GT710 is not meant for gaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to fit a low-profile nVidia GTX 1050 or 1050Ti in there, and that card would allow *some* modern gaming, but that is definitely not a gaming PC.  The GT710 is an old business-class video card that is often used to allow multiple monitors on the same workstation, but is as bad as some on-die processor video adapters when it comes to processing.

I looked at the spec sheet on that machine; it's designed to be a multimedia micro tower.  Even the top end configuration for it only has a GT730 video card, and thats not much better than the 710.  It *does* have an available 90w power supply upgrade, but as you discovered, even the most basic gaming setup requires more than that.

You've also got a problem with that Pentium or *hurk* Celeron processor.  Those are flat-out too weak for games.  If it's an Intel processor and it doesn't say "i3", "i5", "i7", or "i9" at the beginning of its name, it's just their low-power junk they sell for cheap, and most games won't run on them at all.

Unfortunately, all I have is bad news.  That computer won't fit your kid's needs.  You discovered that "cheap computer" and "gaming computer" are mutually exclusive.  I tried to find this machine for sale in the USA, but it looks like it would run around $200 if it were available here.  A light gaming computer in that price range won't happen, unless you can pick it up used.